# Which format should I use to submit a paper for review?

Tags: publications, formatting

I am going to submit a paper to the journal of *ACM Transactions on web*, there is an option for attached files named "*File for reviewers*". I guess it is the option I should choose, but I don't know in which format the file should be. As I searched the site there are a word and a latex templates for articles, but they might be for the final version of the paper?

Can I submit it as a unformatted word document, but enhanced for reading? or a pdf but not based on the template on the site? by the way, I found their template awful for the reviewing purpose.

Comment: Please clarify: There is a way to upload your paper, and *in addition* to that, you can attach files for reviewers? If that is the case, you are most probably not meant to attach an alternative version of your paper in a different format. Rather, that is meant for supplementary material that is required for reading the paper but is not currently publicly accessible for one reason or another.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't know its usage, I just thought it is used to send the paper for reviewers!! But you are right, that is not sensible, thanks!

Comment: I agree with O.R.Mapper that "File for reviewers" probably refers to files other than your paper that you want to make available to these reviewers.  These could be other people's papers or your own previous papers or files of data about your work --- anything the reviewers should have but can't easily get unless you provide it.

Answer (score 7):

Submit in the format they ask for, otherwise paper is likely to be rejected without being read. You won't be reviewing the paper, so don't worry about how awful you think it is.

It's all here: tweb.acm.org/author.html including

> Articles must follow the "Small Standard Format" described in the ACM formatting guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be field-dependent. In fields such as mathematics, it's common practice not to worry about fitting the original submission to the journal's specific style. See [Should you conform to journal formatting requirements for the initial submission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36677/should-you-conform-to-journal-formatting-requirements-for-the-initial-submission/36696).

Having said that, the OP concerns ACM Transactions, and I have to go along with Dave Clarke: this journal's Author Guidelines quoted in his answer continue to state that

> Submissions that do not conform to these guidelines will be returned to the authors for correction.